# Get address of link which is already hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I wanted to create a script for tampermonkey, so that when I am **already** over a link and press Shift, then i get a popup with the link's address.

I came up with the below code which works, the popup does open, but it doesnt show any address, only an undefined error.

```
$(document).on('keydown', function ( e ) {
     if (($('a:hover').length > 0) && (e.shiftKey) ) {
       var url = $('a').attr('href');
        alert(url);    
            }
});
```

The solutions I found on the site are about when I start hovering the link (mouseover,mouseenter,mouseleave,etc), but not when I am already hovering it.

my guess is that jquery doesnt know which a element to use from the page but i dont know how to tell it to use the one which is already hovered.

any idea how i can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code is fetching the `href` of the *first* link, not the hovered one.  In your case, the first link apparently did not have an `href` attribute, hence `undefined`.

Here's working code:

```js
$(document).on ('keydown', zEvent => {
    if (zEvent.shiftKey) {
        //-- Use 2 if()s for better performance / less impact on typing.
        var hoveredLink = $('a:hover');
        if (hoveredLink.length) {
            var hoveredURL = hoveredLink.attr ('href');
            console.log ("hoveredURL: ", hoveredURL || "Link has no href.");
        }
    }
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click in this area, then hover over links and press shift.</p>
<a href="Link_1.example">Link 1</a> &emsp; <a href="Link_2.example">Link 2</a> &emsp; <a>Link 3</a>
```

Run the snippet to see it in action.

Comment: sorry for the late replay, but life went in the middle. anyway, I tried your code and it works very well, I only changed the .attr(href) because it sometimes gives the address of the attr and not of the link itself. anyway, thank you very much for your help.